# .NET 8 EF Include() mapper doesn't work - returns an empty list of ratings

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, orm

This is my code that get each type of entreprises and must include the ratings :

```
public async Task<TopFiveTypeDTo> GetTopFiveBytypeyEntreprises()
{
    List<Entreprise> hotels = await apiDbContext.Entreprises
                .Include(e => e.Ratings) // Include Ratings navigation property
                .Where(x => x.Type.Equals("Hotel"))
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Supported)
                .Take(4)
                .ToListAsync();

    List<Entreprise> restaurants = await apiDbContext.Entreprises
                .Include(e => e.Ratings) // Include Ratings navigation property
                .Where(x => x.Type.Equals("Restaurant"))
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Supported)
                .Take(4)
                .ToListAsync();

    List<Entreprise> activities = await apiDbContext.Entreprises
                .Include(e => e.Ratings) // Include Ratings navigation property
                .Where(x => x.Type.Equals("Activity"))
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Supported)
                .Take(4)
                .ToListAsync();

    return new TopFiveTypeDTo()
            {
                Hotels = hotels,
                Restaurant = restaurants,
                Activities = activities
            };
}
```

The output doesn't use the `.Include()` - it just returns an empty list of ratings

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Currently there is not enough info to reproduce/explain the behavior.

Comment: Add your entity definitions. Also check that your connection string at runtime is pointing at the database you think it is. (`string checkMeWithBreakpoint = .Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;`) It's surprising how often that catches people out where it's picking up/creating a different database instance.